# How to configure the site authorization in Spring Boot security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have some authorization problems on Spring Boot security. First in the application.properties, I type the role query like below,

```
# MySQL Queries for AuthenticationManagerBuilder
spring.queries.users-query = SELECT username, password, role FROM blog_user WHERE username=?
spring.queries.roles-query = SELECT username, role FROM blog_user WHERE username=?
```

And I made the Spring Boot security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BlogWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/" ,"/home*", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/icon/**", "/users/login", "/users/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users", "/posts/create", "posts/view", "/tags/create").hasAnyRole("USER") // only .permitAll() method makes it work.
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and() 
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/users/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error/403");
    }

     @Bean 
     public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
         return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
     }
}
```

`.hasAnyRole("USER")` line works not good. The site "/users", "/posts/create", "posts/view", "/tags/create" throws 404 errors. I mean my 'USER' role codes have some problems. When I change the role method `.hasAnyRole("USER")` to `.permitAll()` method, then it makes work. How can I put the right authorization role codes to my system?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: sorry for my poor english. I will do my best to use the technical expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of role in your blog_user table should be prefixed with ROLE_ (ie. it should be ROLE_USER).

Spring Security 4 always adds the ROLE_ prefix while checking hasRole().
See Spring [security 3 to 4 migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-role-prefixing) for futher information.